# Image of punctured disk around essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions, singularity

I am studying Picard's great theorem in complex analysis and I saw two different forms of theorem.For instance in convoy the theorem is stated as:

> **Great Picard's Theorem**: If an analytic function $f$ has an essential singularity at a point $w$, then on any punctured neighborhood of $w, f(z)$ takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single exception, infinitely often.

While my text book *foundations of complex analysis* by S Ponnusamy states the same theorem as follows:

> Suppose that in $f$ is analytic in $\Delta(z_0;r)$\{$z_0$}(punctured disk around $z_0$ with radius r) and $z=z_0$ is an essential singularity of $f$.Then $\mathbb{C}$\ $f$ ($\Delta(z_0;r)$ \{$z_0$}) is singleton.

Clearly according to first statement,the image of punctured disk around essential singularity may be either whole complex plane or a complex plane minus one point but according to second statement of the same theorem the the image of punctured disk around essential singularity is complex plane with one exception.If I suppose that statement of first book is more precise(convoy) then there is a possibility of a analytic function such that image of punctured disk around essential singularity is whole complex plane,if such a example exists then please provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think $f(z)=\sin\frac1z$ works, doesn't it?

Comment: How?Can you explain a little more?

Comment: It seems the discrepancy is: (1) the first one says the whole plane with at most one exception, whereas (2) the second one says  the whole plane with exactly one exception.

Comment: I wonder that statement given by second author is not correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example is given by $$f(z)=\sin\frac1z$$  We must show that given $r>0$ and $w\in\mathbb{C}$ there exists a $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\zeta|<r$ and $\sin\frac1\zeta=w$  or what is the same thing, that there is a $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|>\frac1r$ and $\sin z =w$.

Solving for $z$,
$$\begin{align}
&\sin z=w\\
&e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2iw\\
&e^{2iz}-2iwe^{iz}-1=0\\
&e^{iz}=\frac{2iw\pm\sqrt{-4w^2+4}}2
\end{align}$$
The right-hand side cannot be $0$, so there is a $z$ that satisfies the equation.  Then by periodicity of $e^z$, there is a $z$ with arbitrarily large modulus that satisfies the equation.

Comment: Nice.One more question,what would we say about  statement (in post) given by second author (S Ponnusamy's)?is the statement not correct??

Comment: It appears to be false, unless the author is using an unusual meaning of "singleton".  I suspect that it's just a mistake.  BTW, looking back at my answer, there's no need to split $w=0$ out as a separate case, but of course, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I don't understand why you used the periodicity though the phrase *there is a z that satisfies the equation* completes the proof

Comment: And BTW how you used the fact of periodicity here?

Comment: We need to show that there is a $z$ of arbitrarily large modulus that satisfies the equation, but if $z$ satisfies the equation, so does $z+2n\pi$ for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Got it,thanks a lot